# Dense subalgebras of von Neumann algebras and increasing nets

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

[Question previously asked on Math.SE]

Let $N$ be a von Neumann algebra, and $A$ be a dense $∗$-subalgebra of $N$ (in the ultraweak topology) with $A''=N$. Is it true that:

For any $x∈N^+$, there exists a increasing net $(x_j)$ in $A^+$ such that $x_j \to x$ in the ultraweak topology ?

The case of $A$ being an ideal of $N$ seems known (it is right?) but my question is about the general case.

(Precision: $A$ is not supposed to be normed closed.)

Comment: Have you considered the case when $N$ is abelian?  E.g., $N = L^\infty[0,1]$, and $A = C[0,1]$.

Comment: If $A=C[0,1]$ as in Jesse's example above, for positive $t$ the functions $f_{t}(x)=min\{f(x),t\}$ will give us an increasing net converging to $f$. The trouble is that when $A$ is strictly smaller than $C[0,1]$ we can't know if such functions are to be found in $A$. Isn't this your problem, Michael?

Comment: Michael specifies explicitly that the subalgebra $A$ does not have to be norm-closed. In that case, an easy counter-example is the following: Consider the algebra of polynomials $A$ in $N=L^{\infty}([-1,1])$. Consider $f=1_{[0,1]}$ the characteristic function of half this interval. The constant function $0$ is the only positive function in $A$ that is also below $f$. Hence you can not approximate $f$ from below by positive polynomials.

Comment: Steven's got it. Whatever you're trying to do, Michael, you're going to need some extra conditions on your dense *-subalgebra!


Comment: @Jon:  $f_t$ need not be continuous if $f$ isn't.

Comment: @Jesse: I wasn't clear. I wanted "$A$ strictly smaller" to indicate that there would be trouble looking at proper *-subalgebras of $C[0,1]$, not that $A$ should be an arbitrary $*$-subalgebra of $L^{\infty}$. So, in that case, $f$ is cts. (Steven's counterexample did the trick already so my comment is irrelevant!) 

Comment: Even if you suppose $A$ to be norm closed you still have counterexamples.  E.g. consider $C[0,1]$ as a weakly dense C*-subalgebra of $\ell^\infty[0,1]$ rather than $L^\infty[0,1]$.  Then the characteristic function of any point in $[0,1]$ certainly can not be approximated from below by positive continuous functions.  If you also want the von Neumann algebra to be countably generated like $L^\infty[0,1]$, then replace $\ell^\infty[0,1]$ with $\ell^\infty([0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q})$.